# Pass data array to interact function?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, interactive

Is it possible to pass data arrays (numpy arrays) to the interact function ?
My data are loaded from a csv file [bad.csv](http://dl.free.fr/giBC1Y1Eo) and stored into numpy arrays: `u`, `v`, `w` and `uNorm` for example.

I've tried to use the following code snippet without luck:

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as mtri
import numpy as np

from IPython.html.widgets import interact, fixed

fileName = './bad.csv'
p,u,v,w,x,y,z  = np.loadtxt(fileName,delimiter=',',skiprows=1,usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6),unpack=True)

uNorm = np.sqrt(u**2 + v**2 + w**2)
r = np.sqrt(y**2 + x**2)
tang = (y / x)

aux_tri = mtri.Triangulation(r/np.max(r), tang/np.max(tang))
triang = mtri.Triangulation(x, y, aux_tri.triangles)
triang.set_mask(mtri.TriAnalyzer(aux_tri).get_flat_tri_mask())

def plotContour(data=w, legendName='Legend', gridOn=True, edgeColors='black'):
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
    plt.tripcolor(triang,data,NbLevels,cmap=cm.hot_r,edgecolors=edgeColors)
    plt.grid(gridOn)
    cbar = plt.colorbar()
    cbar.set_label(legendName,labelpad=10)

interact(plotContour, data={'u':fixed(u),'v':fixed(v),'w':fixed(w),'Magnitude':fixed(uNorm)}, edgeColors=('Black','None'));
```

The first time this snippet is run everything works correctly as the default value for `data` is `w`.

[image]

But when I try to use the dropdown menus I got the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/tri/tripcolor.pyc in tripcolor(ax, *args, **kwargs)
 74     # length of C whether it refers to points or faces.
 75     # Do not do this for gouraud shading.
---> 76     if (facecolors is None and len(C) == len(tri.triangles) and
 77            len(C) != len(tri.x) and shading != 'gouraud'):
 78         facecolors = C

TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

So how to pass numpy arrays in a dropdown menus ?

Comment: Could you provide some more code to get a minimal working example?

Comment: Did you figure this out? thanks

Comment: Also wondering about this in 2020 :-)